# Top to check how many cpus is a process running

Tags: linux, bash

I have an array of 64 java tasks submitted using slurm to a cluster.
I asked 4 cpus per task but suspect that each process is running in only one cpu.
I did `myq` to get the nodes where each task was running

```
Running:
ID           NAME      PART.  QOS     CPU  WALLTIME    REMAIN      NODES
14378773_13  firstrun  batch  normal  4    4-00:00:00  3-12:27:31  node1104
14378773_14  firstrun  batch  normal  4    4-00:00:00  3-12:55:20  node1163
14378773_15  firstrun  batch  normal  4    4-00:00:00  3-14:26:26  node1123

Pending:
ID                  NAME      PART.  QOS     CPU  WALLTIME    EST.START  REASON
14378773_[16-64%6]  firstrun  batch  normal  4    4-00:00:00  N/A        (Priority)
```

Then `ssh` and checked on the 1st one with

```
ssh node1104
top -u mfariasv -H

Threads: 1754 total,  13 running, 1740 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 55.9 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 43.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 19665398+total, 15198475+free, 34527148 used, 10142080 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 15188001+avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 41027 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 R 99.9  6.5 692:18.40 java
 41064 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S 28.7  6.5 224:21.85 java
 41065 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S 28.7  6.5 224:20.59 java
 41066 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S 28.7  6.5 224:21.12 java
 58000 mfariasv  20   0  157900   3972   1484 R  1.0  0.0   0:00.58 top
 41018 mfariasv  20   0  113124   1500   1236 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 slurm_script
 41025 mfariasv  20   0  170856   7276   3300 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 python
 41026 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.00 java
 41028 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.45 java
 41029 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.22 java
 41030 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.18 java
 41031 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.21 java
 41032 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.12 java
 41033 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.03 java
 41034 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:19.78 java
 41035 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.12 java
 41036 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:19.96 java
 41037 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.09 java
 41038 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.36 java
 41039 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.04 java
 41040 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.14 java
 41041 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.28 java
 41042 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:19.73 java
 41043 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.60 java
 41044 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:19.83 java
 41045 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:20.44 java
 41046 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:07.42 java
 41047 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.00 java
 41048 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.00 java
 41049 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.00 java
 41050 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:04.13 java
 41051 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:05.00 java
 41052 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:10.56 java
 41053 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:11.44 java
 41054 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:07.49 java
 41055 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:08.18 java
 41056 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:07.18 java
 41057 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:05.80 java
 41058 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.58 java
 41059 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.56 java
 41060 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.61 java
 41061 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.52 java
 41062 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:00.00 java
 41063 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 S  0.0  6.5   0:04.86 java
 57857 mfariasv  20   0  136068   2100    912 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
 57858 mfariasv  20   0  113880   2040   1516 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
```

As I suspected the process is only running in one cpu, right?

```
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 41027 mfariasv  20   0 36.424g 0.012t  53720 R 99.9  6.5 692:18.40 java
```

When I do `1` while `top` is running I get

```
top - 11:29:17 up 55 days, 21:26,  1 user,  load average: 17.37, 17.46, 17.43
Threads: 1064 total,  18 running, 1045 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu0  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu13 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu14 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu15 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu16 : 22.9 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 77.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu17 :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu18 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu19 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu20 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu21 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu22 : 22.9 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 77.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu23 : 23.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 76.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu24 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu25 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu26 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu27 :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu28 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu29 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu30 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu31 :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 19663889+total, 16113785+free, 29435768 used,  6065264 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 16099705+avail Mem
```

Comment: Right now you are just observing total CPU usage. If you press `I` (`Shift + i`) while `top` is running. You can see a percentage of each available CPU power being used. That way you'll be able to see if all cores are being utilized.

Comment: Just edited my question to add the results of this. Is this running in 4 cores then? Thxs!

Comment: I'm sorry about this, I meant to say that if you press the `1` key, it will show a breakdown of CPU usage per CPU.

Comment: This seems to show all cpus in use in the node, but not which ones under my user (see update in the question above). Or I'm reading this wrong? Thxs!